# Intuition behind Definition of Nilpotent Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition, nilpotent-groups

> **Definition:** A group $G$ is called **nilpotent** if there exists a chain of subgroups $N_0, N_1,\ldots, N_k$ such that $$\{e\} = N_0 \le N_1 \le N_2 \le ... \le N_k = G$$ and for $0\le i\le k-1$,
>
> 1. $N_i \vartriangleleft G$, i.e. $N_i$ is normal in $G$,
> 2. $N_{i+1}/N_i \subset Z(G/N_i)$

where $Z(G)$ denotes the center of some group $G$, and $e$ is the identity of $G$.

What motivated this definition? What is so special about $N_{i+1}/N_i \subset Z(G/N_i)$? It feels so random and out of the blue!

Comment: Write down this upper central series for an easy example, like the Heisenberg group. Then one has more "intuition", because everything is explicit. "Out of the blue" often means, you haven't done enough examples yourself. Some other examples can be found at this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080830/g-with-a-central-series-that-is-different-from-the-upper-and-the-lower-central), where some other examples of series are shown, so that you can compare.

Comment: I would vote up the comment of @DietrichBurde multiple times if I could, and I'll add these thoughts. How did you do when first presented with other definitions from group theory, such as: the definition of a group; the definition of a subgroup; the definition of a coset; the definition of a normal subgroup; the definition of a quotient group; and so on. Which of these felt "out of the blue"? Which felt motivated? And what eventually led you to understand them? Learning how to understand new definitions is an important general mathematical skill you'll need to develop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like the [nLab description](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nilpotent+group), which phrases nilpotent groups in terms of towers of central extensions. In this guise it's a generalization of being abelian.

An extension of a group $G$ is a group $E$ such that $G$ is a quotient of $E$. It's actually slightly more--it's a short exact sequence $1 \to A \to E \to G \to 1$, effectively a "witness" to the fact that $G$ is a quotient of $E$.

A central extension is a group extension as above where additionally $A$ is central in $E$, i.e. (the image of) every element of $A$ commutes with everything in $E$, including all of $A$ itself, so $A$ in particular is abelian. As an example, the central extensions of $G=1$ are precisely the abelian groups.

What are the central extensions of abelian groups? What about the central extensions of central extensions of abelian groups, etc.? Well, whatever they are, we call them nilpotent groups.

The central series can be thought of as a "witness" to this iterated construction. The successive quotients are the central subgroups we're extending by.

Another reason this is a nice definition is that solvable groups are pretty transparent: they're iterated *abelian* extensions, rather than central extensions, a somewhat weaker constraint. That tracks back to [solvability in Galois theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753328/what-is-the-final-intuition-of-galois-solvable-groups-and-radical-solutions).

Comment: I'm going to bookmark this answer so that I can come back to it multiple times and eventually digest all its details :-)